# android butterknife not working and android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, butterknife

I am trying to use the butterknife plugin in android studio but I keep getting the following error:

> Error: Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.

I have followed and done all the steps on the github for butterknife.  Below is the code I have for both the project level and app level gradle files:

## app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ilove.butterknifedemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

## project

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You can just remove the ButterKnife Gradle plugin and it'll work, but don't forget to add the right proguard rules if you need to proguard

Comment: As EpicPandaForce answered if you just want to add Butterknife to your project as a dependency instead in a library, just remove the butterknife plugin and the classpath dependency on your buil.gradle project.

Just ensure to add the dependencies of compile and the annotation processor in the build.gradle file of your module.

Answer (score 1):

change the version of gradle:3.0.0 to 2.3.3

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```